# Cannot install paho-mqtt in Python 3.x

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have installed paho-mqtt on raspberry pi running wheezy with both python 2.7 and 3.5 on board.  Documents say paho will work for python 3.x equally but cannot get it to install. It only installs to 2.7 using pip.  Any clues how to get it to work on 3.1 I installed it fine on Windows version of python 3.5.2 but not via raspberry. Did dist-upgrade before trying.

Comment: have you tried `pip3 install paho-mqtt`? `pip` may be pointing to `python2.7`, usually `pip3` differentiates `python3.x`'s pip from `python2.x`'s pip

Comment: I tried pip3 and got 'command not found' (even tried as sudo). Tried to install python3-pip to find it was already installed???? Not sure where to go next.  Is there a specific syntax in Wheezy to trigger pip3???

Comment: To run a pip install for python 3.x i found that the command line should start with pip-3.2 not pip3.  Works fine using pip-3.2 install paho-mqtt. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't familiar with Ubuntu specifically, glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: It is a good practice to post your solution as the "answer" in a way others can benefit with it, without have to read the comments...

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu as a Linux based system the following worked for installing Paho with Python3

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto
sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
sudo python3 -m pip install paho-mqtt
```

It may be that the final python3 install succeeds without the proceeding steps. Above was the sequence of installs which succeeded after the standard `pip3 install paho-mqtt` failed to install the library correctly.  Best of luck!